# How to Scroll to position of page using get method?

Tags: php, css

How to  Scroll to position of page using get method ?

```
EG: mysite.com/index.php?positon=1
```

after load page it's will be Scroll to position `id=1` of page

how can i do that ?

Comment: `mysite.com/index.php?positon=1#1` if variable is also required in php, `mysite.com/index.php#1` if not

Answer (score 0):

You could use this javascript function :

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value)     {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

For example when your url is : `mysite.com/index.php?positon=1`
You can get the value by doing : `var position = getUrlVars()["position"];`

Then to scroll you do :

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curtop];
    }
}

window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById(position)));
```

You have to use that after the DOM has loaded so write that just after `</body>` like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value)     {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }


    var position = getUrlVars()["position"];


    function findPos(obj) {
        var curtop = 0;
        if (obj.offsetParent) {
            do {
                curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return [curtop];
        }
    }

     window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById(position)));

 })();

 </script>
```

You can then reuse these functions for any variables you want

I can't show you on JSFiddle because the `?position=1` won't work on it
However here is a paste of a fully working html page which I used for testing :   http://pastebin.com/tjj4fDK9
Paste it in a html file on your computer, open it with Chrome and add `?position=1` in the URL